# ORDER BY RAND en registros

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

alguien sabe ¿como se usa el orden by rand? para mostrar registros aleatorios de una tabla. me podrian mostrar un ejemplo cualquiera?

```
SELECT nombre, precio FROM productos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo puedes notar que le pido me muestre valores aleatorios de una tabla llamada productos:

> La calidad de las consultas dependerá de la cantidad de información que
>   tengas almacenada y que deseas mostrar, obviamente debes considerar
>   que este método solo se aplique bajo determinados criterios donde el
>   usuario estrictamente necesite ver valores distintos cada vez que lo
>   solicite. Lo útil es que como tu mismo pones en el ejemplo uses al
>   final `LIMIT` para indicarle cuantos registros únicamente debe
>   considerar

```
SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY RAND();
```

> Tantas veces yo ejecute dicha consulta, serán las mismas veces que los
>   resultados se muestren ordenados de distinto modo

Ahora si bajo esa misma lógica quieres delimitar cuantos registros mostrar, tal cual aparece tu query sería asi:

```
SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

> Una vez mas la calidad y orden de los resultados de dicha consulta van
>   a depender totalmente de la cantidad de veces que sea ejecutada la
>   misma para que notes resultados

Answer (score 0):

**Segun la documentación:**

> Este método funciona generando un valor aleatorio para cada fila de la
>   tabla, clasificando la tabla de acuerdo con estos valores aleatorios y
>   luego devolviendo una fila.

**En otras Palabras**: Esta consulta devuelve aleatoriamente los datos de una consulta

**Ventaja:** Fácil de recordar y usar en consultas complejas de SQL y no necesita tener un campo de ID de asignación única o de incremento automático en su tabla. Seleccione fácilmente múltiples filas aleatorias simplemente aumentando el LÍMITE.

**Desventaja:** la velocidad de este método está directamente relacionada con el tiempo que lleva generar un valor aleatorio para cada fila. Cuantas más filas tenga una tabla, más tiempo tardará.

**Ejemplo:** Devuelve 10 registros con el nombre y el precio de la tabla productos:

```
SELECT nombre, precio FROM productos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```